# Displaying fancy equations with Java

Tags: java, math, open-source

I'm working on a Java applet that needs to display "fancy" equations. Is there any Java renderer for MathML or LaTeX that's open source? Ideally it would be a pure Java solution that doesn't use JNI.

Ideally it would also allow to animate the generated glyphs (e.g. animating adding a constant to both sides of a equation, lines going through terms for cancellation, etc.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know these libraries for Java:

- [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) (MathML renderer; Apache License)
- [JLatexMath](https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath) (Latex renderer; GNU License) improved [JMathTeX](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/)
- [JMathTeX](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/) (Latex renderer; GNU License)
- [HotEqn](http://www.atp.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/VCLab/software/HotEqn/HotEqn.html) (Latex renderer; GNU License ?)
- [SnuggleTex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) (Latex renderer; BSD License)

For the animation part of your question, you can look at these projects:

- [DragMath](https://github.com/maths/dragmath) equation editor (Swing interface; GNU License)
- [Mirai Calc](http://mirai.sourceforge.net/) calculator (SWT interface; GNU License; uses JMathTeX)
- [Java Swing Equation builder](https://github.com/oliverwatkins/calculation_project)

For a web interface you can also use the [jsMath JavaScript](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) or it's successor [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) library as a Latex/MathML renderer.

Comment: JMathTeX and DragMath look *perfect*. Thank you so much!

Comment: jsMath I have found to be common, but often the equations are not rendered at all on the linux machines I have used due to missing libraries.

Comment: this answer work for swing, swt and awt , but for javaFX can we use this ?

Comment: Is there any documentation or examples on how to use JMathTex to render formulae or equations?

Comment: Can we use this Libraries for Android i have been using MathJax which works very slow.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/), it seems to do the first part of what you want.