# Showing a mathematical series in JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing

How can I show a mathemetical series in a JLabel?

Right now I do it like this by using a String with HTML tags.

```
String s = "<html>&Sigma;<sup>N</sup><sub>i = 0</sub> x <sub>i</sub></html>";
```

Result:
[image]

Is there a nicer way to do this? Because the output is very ugly. Usually `N` should be above the sigma and `i = 0` below.

Comment: It would be great if you can add an image of your actual input!

Comment: @nachokk Added the result.

Comment: +1 then to the question xD, i believe that with some style may work but im not good at all in that

Comment: Some potentially useful libraries are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/456002/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nicer way to do this is using a third party library to render [Latex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) code in Java.

There are several of them for example [JLatexMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/), here's a [example tutorial](http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/2868).

For instance, using the program of that example your summatory could look like this:

[image: example 1]

Or like this:

[image: example 2]

Comment: One more reason to start working with TeX.. Much better results as with simple HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I found only the following solution.

```
String s = "<html><table border='0'><tr>"
            + "<td style='font-size: larger'>&Sigma;</td>"
            + "<td style='font-size: smaller'>N<br>i = 0</td>"
            + "<td> x <sub>i</sub></td>"
            + "</tr></table>"
```

Comment: This gives a nicer output. Is there a possibility to show N above the sigma and i = 0 below? Or is this not possible at all?

Comment: With the second `td align=center` the "lines" `N` and `i=0` will be centered (Java 8).

Comment: Maybe 2 `<br>`s and `td valign=middle` look better.