# Display Math Formula in javaFX

Tags: java, math, javafx, latex, javafx-8

I want to know how to display math formula in a label for exemple in JavaFX.
Like this picture :
[image: Sample formula]
I want the .jar of a library and a small example in JavaFX.
I already found some libraries but they are only for Swing/AWT. I tried some of them, but they don't work for me.

[Displaying fancy equations with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456002/displaying-fancy-equations-with-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `JLaTeXMath` is using the `Graphics2D` API for rendering, you can use [FXGraphics2D](https://github.com/jfree/fxgraphics2d) to draw the output to a JavaFX `Canvas`.  For sample code, please refer to my answer to another similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037747/2592874

Answer (score 3):

Just a copy from my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037747/2592874

The next coming versions of JavaFX support MathML :

- JavaFX 8 Update 192 included in Java 8 Update 192
- JavaFX 11.

Just use a WebView control and MathML and set HTML Content with :

```
<math display="block"> 
   <mrow> 
      <mi>x</mi> 
      <mo>=</mo> 
      <mfrac> 
         <mrow> 
            <mo>−</mo> 
            <mi>b </mi> 
            <mo>±</mo> 
            <msqrt> 
               <mrow> 
                  <msup> 
                     <mi>b</mi> 
                     <mn>2</mn> 
                  </msup> 
                  <mo>−</mo> 
                  <mn>4</mn> 
                  <mi>a</mi> 
                  <mi>c</mi> 
               </mrow> 
            </msqrt> 
         </mrow> 
         <mrow> 
            <mn>2</mn> 
            <mi>a</mi> 
         </mrow> 
      </mfrac> 
   </mrow>
</math>
```

Follow the link [JavaFX / OpenJFX Download](http://openjfx.io/) to reach JavaFX version 11 and beyond. 
Follow the link [Java Early Access Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) to reach the early access to these versions.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at [JLatexMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/), mentioned in your referenced answer, and it can genereate a BufferedImage.
With [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) you can convert it to a JavaFX [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) and use it in your application.

The same approach might work for one of the other libraries.