# Running swing application in javaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a code that work perfectly on Swing but I want to integrate it on javaFX.
I know that I must use SwingNode but the code dosen't work in javaFX.
this is .jar of librarie I use : http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/downloads/694/

this is the result in swing :
[image]

this is the code in Swing :

```
 import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXIcon;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class LatexExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea latexSource;
    private JButton btnRender;
    private JPanel drawingArea;

    public LatexExample() {
        this.setTitle("JLatexMath Example");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        Container content = this.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        this.latexSource = new JTextArea();

        JPanel editorArea = new JPanel();
        editorArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        editorArea.add(new JScrollPane(this.latexSource),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editorArea.add(btnRender = new JButton("Render"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        content.add(editorArea);
        content.add(this.drawingArea = new JPanel());
        this.btnRender.addActionListener(this);

        this.latexSource.setText("x=\\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}");
    }

    public void render() {
        try {
            // get the text
            String latex = this.latexSource.getText();

            // create a formula
            TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(latex);

            // render the formla to an icon of the same size as the formula.
            TeXIcon icon = formula
                    .createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);

            // insert a border
            icon.setInsets(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

            // now create an actual image of the rendered equation
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                    icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(Color.white);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
            JLabel jl = new JLabel();
            jl.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            icon.paintIcon(jl, g2, 0, 0);
            // at this point the image is created, you could also save it with ImageIO

            // now draw it to the screen
            Graphics g = drawingArea.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LatexExample frame = new LatexExample();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if( e.getSource()==this.btnRender ) {
            render();
        }

    }
}
```

and this is JavaFX version (dosen't work nothing appear) :

```
private void createAndSetSwingContent() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    // get the text
                    String latex = "x=\\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}";

                    // create a formula
                    TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(latex);

                    // render the formla to an icon of the same size as the formula.
                    TeXIcon icon = formula
                            .createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);

                    // insert a border
                    icon.setInsets(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

                    // now create an actual image of the rendered equation
                    final BufferedImage images = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                            icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics2D g2 = images.createGraphics();
                    g2.setColor(Color.white);
                    g2.fillRect(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
                    label.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
                    icon.paintIcon(label, g2, 0, 0);
                    // at this point the image is created, you could also save it with ImageIO


                    panel = new JPanel(){
                        @Override
                        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
                        {
                            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                            g.drawImage(images, 0, 0, null);
                        }
                    };
                    swingNode.setContent(label);
                    swingNode.setContent(panel);


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: `super.paintComponent` as 1st. code line inside protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` will reduce possible painting lacks

Comment: override `getPreferredSize` inside `panel = new JPanel(){`

Comment: please cleanup your code before dumping it onto us (fishy f.i. creating a graphics2d without using it, setting swingnode's content twice ...)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.for @kleopatra I understand well the first comment but the last one I didn't understand well.

Comment: as you accepted David's answer, my implicit assumption (problem unrelated to the tex library) turned out to be wrong - so my second comment now is useless and deleted :-)

Comment: ah okay thank you anyway for your comments :) @kleopatra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ought to be able to render this output to a JavaFX Canvas using [FXGraphics2D](https://github.com/jfree/fxgraphics2d) and eliminate Swing completely.  I modified one of the sample programs to produce this output (it is a small JavaFX app):

[image: Output from sample program in JavaFX]

Unfortunately drawing the `TeXIcon` directly to the `FXGraphics2D` instance doesn't give nice output (most likely due to issues in the TextLayout rendering that I haven't been able to trace the source of yet), but drawing to an image first (as you did in your example) then drawing the image to the JavaFX Canvas seems to work fine.

```
/* =================
 * FXGraphics2DDemo3
 * =================
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Object Refinery Limited.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/index.html
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *   - Neither the name of the Object Refinery Limited nor the
 *     names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *     derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL OBJECT REFINERY LIMITED BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 */

package org.jfree.fx.demo;

import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXIcon;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027060/running-swing-application-in-javafx
 */
public class FXGraphics2DDemo3 extends Application {

    static class MyCanvas extends Canvas { 

        private FXGraphics2D g2;

        private TeXIcon icon;

        public MyCanvas() {
            this.g2 = new FXGraphics2D(getGraphicsContext2D());

            // create a formula
            TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula("x=\\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}");

            // render the formla to an icon of the same size as the formula.
            this.icon = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);

            // Redraw canvas when size changes. 
            widthProperty().addListener(evt -> draw()); 
            heightProperty().addListener(evt -> draw()); 
        }  

        private void draw() { 
            double width = getWidth(); 
            double height = getHeight();
            getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

            // ideally it should be possible to draw directly to the FXGraphics2D
            // instance without creating an image first...but this does not generate
            // good output
            //this.icon.paintIcon(new JLabel(), g2, 50, 50);

            // now create an actual image of the rendered equation
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                    icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D gg = image.createGraphics();
            gg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            gg.fillRect(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
            JLabel jl = new JLabel();
            jl.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            icon.paintIcon(jl, gg, 0, 0);
            // at this point the image is created, you could also save it with ImageIO

            this.g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean isResizable() { 
            return true;
        }  

        @Override 
        public double prefWidth(double height) { return getWidth(); }  

        @Override 
        public double prefHeight(double width) { return getHeight(); } 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(); 
        stackPane.getChildren().add(canvas);  
        // Bind canvas size to stack pane size. 
        canvas.widthProperty().bind( stackPane.widthProperty()); 
        canvas.heightProperty().bind( stackPane.heightProperty());  
        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane)); 
        stage.setTitle("FXGraphics2DDemo3.java"); 
        stage.setWidth(700);
        stage.setHeight(390);
        stage.show(); 

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

EDIT:  here is a revised version of the program that draws the equation directly (to make this work it is necessary to preload the required fonts that are included in the JLatexMath jar file so that JavaFX can use them):

```
/* =================
 * FXGraphics2DDemo3
 * =================
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Object Refinery Limited.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/index.html
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *   - Neither the name of the Object Refinery Limited nor the
 *     names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *     derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL OBJECT REFINERY LIMITED BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 */

package org.jfree.fx.demo;

import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D;

import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.Box;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXIcon;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027060/running-swing-application-in-javafx
 */
public class FXGraphics2DDemo3 extends Application {

    static class MyCanvas extends Canvas { 

        private FXGraphics2D g2;

        private Box box;

        public MyCanvas() {
            this.g2 = new FXGraphics2D(getGraphicsContext2D());
            this.g2.scale(20, 20);

            // create a formula
            TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula("x=\\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}");
            TeXIcon icon = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);

            // the 'Box' seems to be the thing we can draw directly to Graphics2D
            this.box = icon.getBox();

            // Redraw canvas when size changes. 
            widthProperty().addListener(evt -> draw()); 
            heightProperty().addListener(evt -> draw()); 
        }  

        private void draw() { 
            double width = getWidth(); 
            double height = getHeight();
            getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            this.box.draw(g2, 1, 5);
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean isResizable() { 
            return true;
        }  

        @Override 
        public double prefWidth(double height) { return getWidth(); }  

        @Override 
        public double prefHeight(double width) { return getHeight(); } 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(FXGraphics2DDemo3.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/scilab/forge/jlatexmath/fonts/base/jlm_cmmi10.ttf"), 1);
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(FXGraphics2DDemo3.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/scilab/forge/jlatexmath/fonts/maths/jlm_cmsy10.ttf"), 1);
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(FXGraphics2DDemo3.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/scilab/forge/jlatexmath/fonts/latin/jlm_cmr10.ttf"), 1);
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(); 
        stackPane.getChildren().add(canvas);  
        // Bind canvas size to stack pane size. 
        canvas.widthProperty().bind( stackPane.widthProperty()); 
        canvas.heightProperty().bind( stackPane.heightProperty());  
        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane)); 
        stage.setTitle("FXGraphics2DDemo3.java"); 
        stage.setWidth(700);
        stage.setHeight(390);
        stage.show(); 

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: for the picture drawn , if the equation is so much long I can add the canvas in javafx Scrollpane

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind it being rasterized at a specifc size, you could use the `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage` static method in `javafx.embed.swing`:

```
    TeXFormula tex = new TeXFormula("a + b \\cdot x");
    java.awt.Image awtImage = tex.createBufferedImage(TeXConstants.STYLE_TEXT, 12, java.awt.Color.BLACK, null);
    Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage((BufferedImage) awtImage, null);
    ImageView view = new ImageView(fxImage);
```

The `fxImage` instance could also be passed to the `Labeled.setGraphic` method for use in certain controls (e.g. buttons).

Comment: This solution ended up being the most suitable for my use case. Images seemed to correctly size themselves for the formula with very little white space around the edges (which is perfect in most situations).

Comment: This also worked in my case. I plan on using this for a couple of applications so I have place it in a method. Thanks for this! +1

Answer (score 1):

There's now a port of jlatexmath to javafx, at 
https://github.com/bitstormGER/jlatexmathfx .
It works well, except for a few minor issues, raised on the github page. The project doesn't seem active, but the issues are easy to solve by re-implementing the `LateXMathSkin` class. Hope this would save some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The next coming versions of JavaFX support MathML :

- JavaFX 8 Update 192 included in Java 8 Update 192
- JavaFX 11.

Just use a WebView control and MathML and set HTML Content with :

```
<math display="block"> 
   <mrow> 
      <mi>x</mi> 
      <mo>=</mo> 
      <mfrac> 
         <mrow> 
            <mo>−</mo> 
            <mi>b </mi> 
            <mo>±</mo> 
            <msqrt> 
               <mrow> 
                  <msup> 
                     <mi>b</mi> 
                     <mn>2</mn> 
                  </msup> 
                  <mo>−</mo> 
                  <mn>4</mn> 
                  <mi>a</mi> 
                  <mi>c</mi> 
               </mrow> 
            </msqrt> 
         </mrow> 
         <mrow> 
            <mn>2</mn> 
            <mi>a</mi> 
         </mrow> 
      </mfrac> 
   </mrow>
</math>
```

Follow the link [Java Early Access Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) to reach the early access to these versions.