# JavaFX : Put chemical formula into Label

Tags: java, javafx, label

I was wondering if it was possible to put chemical formulas ( SUB and SUP characters) into a Label content like:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973389/display-math-formula-in-javafx

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456002/displaying-fancy-equations-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using [jlatexmath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/):

```
private void createGraphic(String textValue, Color color) {
    TeXFormula tex = new TeXFormula(textValue);
    java.awt.Image awtImage = tex.createBufferedImage(TeXConstants.STYLE_TEXT, 12, color, null);
    Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage((BufferedImage) awtImage, null);
    label.setGraphic(new ImageView(fxImage));
}
```

Comment: I've added a link to the mentioned library. Please check if it is really the library you meant.