# How to create or add a text editor to input mathematical equations using swing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am working on a project of question paper generator(offline) which requires the the user to input the questions. Obviously there will be some questions of mathematics as well hence I need to invoke or create a text editor that will create mathematical expressions such as integral symbol or limit operator etc.

I am using java swing GUI and mysql database to achieve the purpose and hoping to use `JEditorPane` for text area.
Please help me , I took about a day to search the internet to solve this problem.
And also I need to know whether the mathematical expression the text editor will create could be stored in mysql database column?

---

**Things I tried:-**

- Tried changing the text type of `JEditorPane` to text/html but I realised that I can add subscript, superscript and even images but this wont add that beautiful LaTeX mathematical expressions and many complex operators.
- Tried using *JMathTex* but I couldn't resolve how it will enable the user to input the expressions, according to me *JMathTex* is not the solution to my problem.
- Even thought tries of using *MathJax* but it requires java script and `JEditorPane` does not support java script.

I repeat the problem, I want to create a text editor (*just like MathType*) in my swing application so that user can input the question along with the  required expressions so that the question can be added to database for random generation.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. Can you explain what you tried, what works, and what doesn't?

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question

Comment: @Daniele Look the question now.

Comment: I suppose you could get the [MathType for Java Swing](http://www.wiris.com/en/editor/docs/javaswing) component and use that in your application. I should think that would be the easiest way to take care of business. Why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DevilsHnd can you provide an answer as how to use it

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/462893/24819. Maybe DragMath can help?