# Prettyprint raised to numbers in JTextArea/JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jeditorpane

My program includes a GUI for polynomials, where they enter their polynomials in a JTextArea or JEditorPane.

I'm trying to find a way that whenever the user enters "^(a number)" in the text area that it changes the look to actually show that the number is being an exponent of a letter or number.

so for example n^2 would be seen as the number 2 representing that it is an exponent of n much better.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/462893/3692099

Answer (score 0):

Not in a JTextArea, but in a JEditorPane or JTextPane you can use a StyledDocument.

On key down event of `^` (`KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX`) you add an HTML `<sup>...</sup>` probably with attribute styles on the `StyledDocument`.

This requires some work, as opposed to the ready math solutions of @Schokokuchen_Bäcker.

You could provide an edit icon for `^` like [<sup>x</sup>], especially as one some national keyboards `^` is a dead key to create letters like `û`. Even more work.

A change of character attribute for superscript then corresponds to a `^` in your representation.

As JTextPane is a child class of JEditorPane, I would use that one.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
textPane.setEditable(true);

Element elememt = doc.getCharacterElement(docOffset);
if (StyleConstants.isSuperscript(element.getAttributes())) { ...
```

One might use SimpleAttributeSet to compose attributes.